# que tendria que poner en mi css para que no se vea asi

Tags: css, reactjs

esoty tratando de ajustar estos titulos para que no se vean asi cuando los centro

Adjunto codigo:

```
@media (max-width: 480px ) {
    h1{
      
      font-family: Open Sans;
      font-size: 36px;
      font-weight: 800;
      line-height: 30px;
      letter-spacing: 0em;
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 430px;
      color: white;  
    }
  
    h2{
     
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    margin-left: 430px;
    color: white;
    }
  
}
```

los tiutlos se distorsonian cuando los centro no se porque pase eso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no tendria porque verse asi que tendria que cambiar en el css para que no se vea asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu cuadrado ha de tener **padding** o **margin**. Podrías mostrarnos los estilos que estas aplicando al cuadrado?

Comment: pues no estan dentro de un cuadroel margin que le di es para centrarlas y que se ajusten a una vista de 480px pero en vez de que se vean alineados se ven asi y esos son los estilos que tienen esos componentes

Comment: Quita el `margin-left: 430px;` de **h1** y de **h2** ya que no tiene sentido debido a que lo estás mandando a centrar. coloca tambien **!important** en `text-align: center;`

Comment: lo hice pero no lo centro

Comment: los centro pero los mando a la izquierda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como debes aplicarlo:

```html
<style>
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
        h1{
            font-family: Open Sans;
            font-size: 36px;
            font-weight: 800;
            line-height: 30px;
            letter-spacing: 0em;
            text-align: center;
            color: red;  
        }
    
        h2{
            font-family: Open Sans;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: 30px;
            letter-spacing: 0em;
            text-align: center;
            color: purple;
        }
    }
</style>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tst</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Prueba 1</h1>

    <h2>Prueba 2</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Y así es como debe verse: (Centrado)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: listo ya quedo gracias

Comment: listo ya funciono gracias